# I have an a 4 digit 7 segment display project with an Arduino Nano, but it doesn't work

Tags: arduino, sensors, display, segment

The project is about displaying the temperature on the display.

Circuit contains the following:

- Arduino Nano(AtMega328p)
- 4 digit 7-segment display(Kingbright CA56-12SRWA)
- 74HC595N shift register
- 4x 220ohm resistors for the display
- DHT11 temperature and humidity sensor
- 1k ohm resistor for the sensor

The program:

```
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 7
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

const int latchPin = 5;
const int dataPin = 6;
const int clockPin = 4;

const int digitPins[4] = 
{
    A0, A3, A2, A1  
};

const byte digit[10] =
{
    B01010000, //0
    B11010111, //1
    B01100100, //2
    B01000110, //3
    B11000011, //4
    B01001010, //5
    B01001000, //6
    B11010110, //7
    B01000000, //8
    B01000010 //9
};

int digitBuffer[4] = {0};

int digitScan = 0;

void updateDisp(){
   for(byte j = 0; j < 4; j++){
      digitalWrite(digitPins[j], LOW);
   }

   digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
   shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, B11111111);
   digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);

   delayMicroseconds(100);
   digitalWrite(digitPins[digitScan], HIGH);

   digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
   if(digitScan==1){
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, ~(digit[digitBuffer[digitScan]] | 
B01000000));
   }
   else
   {
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, ~(digit[digitBuffer[digitScan]]));
   }

   digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
   digitScan++;
   if(digitScan > 3){digitScan = 0;}
}

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);

   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      pinMode(digitPins[i], OUTPUT);
   }

   dht.begin();
}

void loop() {

   float h = dht.readHumidity();
   float t = dht.readTemperature();
   float hi = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);

   digitBuffer[3] = int(t)/1000;
   digitBuffer[2] = (int(t)%1000)/100;
   digitBuffer[0] = (int(t)%100)/10;
   digitBuffer[1] = (int(t)%100)%10;
   updateDisp();
   Serial.println(t);
   delay(5);
}
```

The problem, is that the leds don't show numbers, but I tested the binary and in the test program all digits worked. Also nearly every 2 seconds all leds turn of f and then turn on again. In theory there could be no problems with the components, nor with the connections. Please don't be angry if I made a huge mistake somewhere, I'm a beginner. I'm more interested in the circuit part than the coding, I couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have used the code from here
https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHTtester/DHTtester.ino

You system is updating the display too fast, as such the DHT is not able to process the temperature correctly, and ends up giving garbage values.

Increase the delay from 5 (which is 5ms) to about 250 (to 250 ms), you will see digits. I would suggest using 2000ms, but I feel 250 should work.

Comment: I could fix the issue of displaying things that don't make sense, the porblem was that i had to invert the binary of the numbers. But the turning on and off is still an issue. To make it more easy to understandi made a video: https://youtu.be/IaxJ375tIl0

Comment: I just noticed what the problem is.
For your LED matrix to stay lit up, you need to continuously keep scanning through the digits.
But then every 2 seconds, the DHT sensor gives a proper reading, and the library waits in the readHumidity and readTemperature functions.

That's why when the led's go off, 1 digit stays on, and the serial led on your Arduino goes off.

Comment: You need to write the code using timer interrupt, or maybe use 2 Arduino's, 1 for controlling the leds and 1 for measuring from the DHT.

Comment: Thanks for your hhelp, sir.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a MAX7219 chip...